# C++17 dependent name is not a type, works in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct X
{
    void foo(){}
};

class Y { };

template <typename T, typename... U>
class Example {
protected:
    template <template<typename> typename example_t>
    using alias = X<example_t<T>>;

};

template <typename T>
struct ExampleA : public Example<T, Y>
{
    using MyAlias = ExampleA::alias<ExampleA>;
};
```

In C++14 I could do the following and have it work as expected:

```
ExampleA<int>::MyAlias test;
test.foo();
```

A recent upgrade to C++17 now gives a warning `'ExampleA<T>::alias': dependent name is not a type` as well as `syntax error: identifier 'alias'`.

Normally when you get something involving a `dependent name` it means you need to add the `typename` keyword as in the following example (`iterator` is dependent upon `std::vector<T>`):

```
template<typename T> 
void bar() {
    /* typename */ std::vector<T>::iterator it;
}
```

However, I don't believe that to be the case here. Also, using `using MyAlias = Example<T, Y>::alias<ExampleA>;` results in the same error.

Did a change in C++17 invalidate this code, or is this a compiler bug? What can I do to fix this in C++17?

Comment: For a quick fix, this may work: `using MyAlias = typename ExampleA::template alias<ExampleA>;`

Comment: Thanks, that got it to compile. I tried the `typename` prefix and adding `::template` separately but not together. Any idea why it is now required in C++17? Or maybe this is a fix for the C++14 version?

Comment: Is your question MSVC-specific by any chance? If so, you should tag your question appropriately. MSVC's parsing algorithm has been a lot more tolerant than other compilers in the past, and this could just be them starting to be stricter with the language rules. (also, GCC rejects your code regardless of standard version)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I haven't tested it elsewhere so I'm not sure if it's specific to MSVC, but I went ahead and added the tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSVC ignored the abscence of desambiguators due to an implementation detail of their compiler.

With new advances and reengineering of their compiler, they now implement two phase name lookup as they should. However, with that implemented, it's really hard in some cases to ignore absence of desambiguators.

They became even more strict with the `/permissive-` flag, which is an attempt to disable most of their extensions due to their previous lack of two phase name lookup.

Your code snippet look like this with desambiguators:

```
template <typename T>
struct ExampleA : public Example<T, Y>
{
    using MyAlias = typename ExampleA::template alias<ExampleA>;
};
```

See it as an opportunity to upgrade the compilance and portability of your code.

However with C++20, many cases where desambigurator were needed are now optional:

```
template<typename T>
auto wrapper() -> T::type; // no typename!
```

Comment: _"However with C++20, many cases where desambigurator were needed are now optional"_ how come?

Comment: @Timo because some context are actually not ambiguous. Trailing return type is such an example. In C++98, you didn't needed disambiguators for inheritance either. C++20 just updated that for all non ambiguous contexts.